# Java class that represent method name and formal parameters

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a JDK Java class that represents a method name and
formal parameters without the declaraing class. If I use
the Java class Method from java.lang.reflect I usually get

too much information:

```
public class Method

clazz: The declaring class
name: The method name
parameterTypes: The formal parameters
Etc..
```

I am seeking a class which already exists in the JDK
and which would cover:

```
public class ??

name: The method name
parameterTypes: The formal parameters
```

Comment: What about the return type?

Comment: Return type is not required in Class#getDeclaredMethod, see also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no such class in the JDK to the best of my knowledge. But you could create one and use it to generate an actual `java.lang.reflect.Method` by demand:.